# Mixing Data Structures and Objects

Tags: javascript, oop

Uncle Bob says not to mix objects and data structures. I have the following data structure...

```
AccountInfo{
   CCNumber : null,
   CCExpiry : null
}
```

I would like to add a function called .hasAllCreditCardInfo() onto that data structure. But is that a bad idea? Is that turning my data structure into an object?

```
if (AccountInfo.hasAllCreditCardInfo()){
    processPayment();
}
```

Comment: In your case I would make an object called `AccountInfoValidator`, which would handle this type of logic.

Comment: This would definitely help with single responsibility but I'm worried about abstracting too soon...